# Compare two array with position

Tags: php

I have two arrays,

```
$a= array(1,2,3,4,5);
$b= array(2,1,4,4,5);
```

and i want to print (4,5) because it is the element which is same in both given array with same position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
$length = count($a);
$same = array();

for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    if($a[$i] == $b[$i]) {
        $same[] = $a[$i];
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot George , i am new here and you help me with very nicely tricks, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
$c = array();
foreach($a as $key => $val) {
    if($val == $b[$key]) {
        $c[] = $val;
    }
}

var_dump($c);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  int(4)
  [1]=>
  int(5)
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `$key` rather than `key` ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `array_intersect_assoc()` like this:

```
$a = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$b = array(2,1,4,4,5);
$array = array_intersect_assoc($a, $b);
var_dump($array);
```

The `array_intersect_assoc()` function performs similarly to `array_intersect()`, however it adds an extra key check to validate that the keys match as well.

Comment: your edited answer is very useful for me with using this shortcut i am able to do short program. THANK YOU - #Mike